# How do you apply a class everytime you click the button in React?

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I have a slide in animation that I want to kick in everytime one of the dots in the carousel is clicked. However with my current code the state is always true and if I set it to a "toggling" state, it will be "true,false" meaning the class will only be applied every one click of the dots (when is true).

I want the slide in effect to apply on every dot that is clicked. Code here:

JSX

```
const [onClick, setClick] = useState(false);
const handleDotClick = () => {
    setClick(onClick => !onClick);
};

<div className={classnames(styles.grid, { [styles.slideIn]: onClick })}>
     {data[0].map(({ image }) => {
       return (
          <div>
         <Image src={`image.jpg`}/>
          </div>
            );
        })}
</div>
<div className={styles.dots}>
      {Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map((e, i) => (
   <span onClick={handleDotClick}></span>
       ))}
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
  animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to apply the slideIn class everytime the dot is clicked?

Comment: This may help https://medium.com/swlh/the-setstate-hook-for-setting-state-on-an-array-of-children-11e6437880da

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding here is an example using `useRef` to apply the `slideIn` animation on each time a dot is clicked.

```
const ref = useRef();
const handleDotClick = () => {
  if (ref.current) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      ref.current.classList.remove("slideIn");
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      ref.current.classList.add("slideIn");
    });
  }
};

<div ref={ref} className={classnames(styles.grid, { [styles.slideIn]: onClick })}>
  {data[0].map(({ image }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Image src={`image.jpg`} />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
<div className={styles.dots}>
  {Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map((e, i) => (
    <span onClick={handleDotClick}></span>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to be the same as I have, the slideIn effect is applied every 1 dot clicked. There is always a true and a false, meaning always an image that will slide and one that won't whereas the objective is having all images sliding in, one per click.

Comment: @Rpx8989 So instead of entire container `slideIn` animation you want to apply the animation to only one image. Is it correct ?

Comment: the grid represents the image. I have a grid carousel meaning the amount of images differs depending on viewport.

Comment: Please mention this in the question and add some images if possible. It is not clear from the question and the code that is provided.